# Low execution time (100ms) high fetch time (4s) but other queries are fine

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm having a really odd issue.

The query takes 100ms to prepare and execute but 3-7 - 4.1s fetch time.  The total data returned is only about 16KBs of data (which is accurate) but other queries that have much more data and execute in the same time also return in <100ms range.

Why would one query have such a high fetch time but others much lower?

It tells me it wouldn't be a network issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) That will help you to find what is wrong with your queries